# Disable right click protection to work in webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I'm doing a webview in android studio, the website has protection (the right click does not work) the client wants to leave that option, what can I do to make the webview work? I do not upload images, I can not click on entries or notifications

Comment: Hi and Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide more information so people can help you: What is this website that you're referring to, and how is "right click" relevant when dealing with Android? What is it exactly that doesn't work? What do you want to achieve? Can you show us what you tried / provide code?

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer, I will explain myself a little better, 

My client has a website made in wordpress and wants to make a webview.

Your website has a plugin that blocks the right click of the mouse and the wordpress theme that it uses was created.

When I'm going to create the webview and export it in apk I see that the top image does not load and that in some places the touch does not take effect.

Can I fix that from the webview (android Studio) or should the client change his wordpress theme?

I think the problem is from my client's website

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I'm not 100% confident but it sounds like your client's website is not [Responsive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) to mobile devices. If you can provide a screenshot, it'll help me verify my guess.

Comment: if it is responsive, when i go from google chrome in my samsung s9 everything is displayed perfect but in the webview it does not appear well.

I do not publish it because I do not have permission from my client and he can dislike me, sorry

Comment: hi @Zoe, excuse my mistake, I did not know that rule, it will not happen again. Thanks for notifying me, have a nice day